# Do living beings of different sizes perceive time differently?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, time

Do living beings having different sizes e.g. an ant and an elephant perceive time at different rates? Is the physical time same for all sizes or different for different sizes?

Suppose There is a being existing in the intergalactic space and I am able to observe the movement of the galaxies. Relative to me 1 sec of time is the time in which I may observe the galaxies to travel with a noticeable speed,but relative to a human on Earth 1 sec is infinitesimally small time for the galaxies to travel at the same speed as observed by the giant being.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what the first part of the question (ants) has to do with the second one (galaxies). Could you explain?

Comment: You made your question more philsophical than needed for the purpose of CogSci. This seems to answer your question - though the scientific validity of the responses is questionable. https://www.quora.com/Perception/Do-different-animals-including-humans-perceive-time-differently

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate of the newer one since I felt it's phrasing was focused a bit less philosophically, and, it attracted more useful discussion in comments already.